# search for pattern and remove all lines

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have system logs where alarms are written. in my case i have lots of repeated alarms which i want to ignore and focus only on new alarms that might be exist.

sample alarm :

```
 kbl1infn8:CCC_USER_2049.0002:2016/09/20-17:00:03.560451-00540-03276-CCC_USER_2049- <0N CpocsSs7CircuitCat#040200000000009a|6501646464644309|6501646464c90000-6503010117c80000-1.0.3|a40200003e3d8fd5|0000000e|0000000000000000
    kbl1infn8:CCC_USER_2049.0002:2016/09/20-17:00:03.560451-00540-03276-CCC_USER_2049- |RC USSDString=*1234*#|MSISDN=93707678224|
    kbl1infn8:CCC_USER_2049.0002:2016/09/20-17:00:03.560451-00540-03276-CCC_USER_2049- |NF NOT: src=ERROR_APPLICATION sev=SEVERITY_MAJOR id=010117c800000001
    kbl1infn8:CCC_USER_2049.0002:2016/09/20-17:00:03.560451-00540-03276-CCC_USER_2049- de.siemens.advantage.in.featureframework.FeatureException: GenAcc> [0]theGenericAccess: No value available for SubsDMDB.Subscriber.LanguageID and type INTEGER
    kbl1infn8:CCC_USER_2049.0002:2016/09/20-17:00:03.560451-00540-03276-CCC_USER_2049-  at de.siemens.advantage.in.features.genericAccess.impl.DynamicAsciiBuffer$Handle.throwNotAvailableException(DynamicAsciiBuffer.java:1105)

--
kbl1infn4:CCC_USER_1025.0009:2016/09/20-00:23:03.981403-25661-28403-CCC_USER_1025- <0N CpocsSs7CircuitCat#020200000000008a|6501646464644309|6501646464c90000-6501646464640000-1.1.1|a20200003cc
31dd2|0000000e|0000000000000000
kbl1infn4:CCC_USER_1025.0009:2016/09/20-00:23:03.981403-25661-28403-CCC_USER_1025- |RC CdPA=173|CgPA=93705040139|
kbl1infn4:CCC_USER_1025.0009:2016/09/20-00:23:03.981403-25661-28403-CCC_USER_1025- |NF NOT: src=ERROR_APPLICATION sev=SEVERITY_MAJOR id=6503010103c80016
kbl1infn4:CCC_USER_1025.0009:2016/09/20-00:23:03.981403-25661-28403-CCC_USER_1025- Exception in flexible core (e.g. during logic execution):de.siemens.advantage.in.featureframework.FeatureExc
eption: Call.checkIfCcOperationIsAllowed():  operation Call.playAnnouncement() only allowed within an open call control dialog
kbl1infn4:CCC_USER_1025.0009:2016/09/20-00:23:03.981403-25661-28403-CCC_USER_1025-  at de.siemens.advantage.in.features.flexDTMF.actions.dtmfActions.impl.DTMFActionsController.playAnnounc
ementList(DTMFActionsController.java:360)
--
```

the above lines are related to one alarms. here i want to omit such alarm in my log file.

I have tried using   `grep -v 'RC USSDString' IN-201609201800.txt | more` but this command removes only the line where the searched pattern `grep -v 'RC USSDString' IN-201609201800.txt | more` does exist, where i want to remove the entire lines of alarm where  pattern is found.

**Edit:**
- I have added one more alarm separated by double dash

Comment: `awk -v RS="" '!/RC USSDString/' IN-201609201800.txt` try this

Comment: Please provide two alarms, need to find how they are separated to others.

Comment: @PS. it doesn't work :(  I have added one more alarm

Comment: can you add expected output explicitly?

Comment: @Sundeep i want to list all alarms except the alarm contains a certain pattern

Comment: that is still not clear to me.. that is why I asked to add expected output to your given sample input... do you mean one alarm log is multiline and separated by `--`, and your problem statement is to print except such multiline alarm log based on pattern found anywhere on those multiple lines?

Comment: try  `awk -v RS="--" '{$1=$1} !/RC USSDString/' alarmfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your alarms are multi line and two alarms are separated with each other by `--`.

```
awk -v RS="--" '{$1=$1} !/RC USSDString/' alarmfile
```

If you want to add , multiple string to be excluded from output then:

```
awk -v RS="--" '{$1=$1} !/string-1/ || !/string-2/' alarmfile
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do :

```
grep -Ev 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3' file
```

Comment: this removes only the line where the patterns is found. i want to remove other lines on the alarm